# How to derive the formulae for Poisson confidence intervals?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, confidence-interval

I have been struggling to derive the formulae for CI of Poisson distribution parameters.

Suppose I have a sample $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Parameter $\lambda=\theta$ is what I want a CI for.

Given $n,\overline{X}$ as well as the confidence level $\gamma$, I consider the statistic:
$$T(X)=n\overline{X}$$
which is a sum of $n$ independent Poisson  random variable, thus a $\text{Poisson}(n\theta)$ r.v.
Its CDF is
$$F_{\theta}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{(n\theta)^k}{e^{n\theta}k!}$$
Checking for monotonicity:
$$\frac{\partial F_{\theta}(t)}{\partial\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{nk(n\theta)^{k-1}e^{n\theta}-n\theta e^{n\theta}(n\theta)^k}{e^{n\theta}k!}=\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{(n\theta)^{k-1}n(k-n\theta)}{e^{n\theta}k!}$$
which is negative for any $k<n\overline{X}$, therefore $F_{\theta}(t)$ is decreasing from 0 to $n\overline{X}$.

The CI is then given by
$$(\underline{\theta_n},\overline{\theta_n})=(\theta:\gamma_1<F_{\theta}(T+0),F_{\theta}(T)<\gamma_2)\quad\text{where }\gamma_2-\gamma_1=\gamma$$
where
\begin{align*}
&F_{\theta}(T)=\sum_{k=0}^{T}\frac{(n\theta)^k}{e^{n\theta}k!}\\
&F_{\theta}(T+0)=\sum_{k=0}^{T+1}\frac{(n\theta)^k}{e^{n\theta}k!}\end{align*}
Using the relationship between Poisson and $\chi^2$, write:
\begin{align*}
&F_{\theta}(T)=1-H_{2(n\overline{X})}(2n\theta)=\gamma_2\\
&F_{\theta}(T+0)=1-H_{2(n\overline{X}+1)}(2n\theta)=\gamma_1
\end{align*}
where H is the CDF of the $\chi^2$-distribution with 2T or 2T+2 degrees of freedom respectively.

I understand, I need to show that $n\underline{\theta}=\chi^2_{\frac{1-\gamma}{2}},n\overline{\theta}=\chi^2_{\frac{1+\gamma}{2}}$ for $\chi^2$-distributions with 2T and 2T+2 degrees of freedom respectively, but I don't know how to argue to obtain this result after the transition from Poisson to $\chi^2$.

My question is, how do I proceed to derive the formulae that allow to calculate the CI?

I have seen the threads with solved numeric examples and I did read the articles about multiple ways to evaluate this CI, but none of this addressed my problem above, hence the question.

Comment: There are at least a dozen styles of CIs for Poisson $\lambda$ in common usage. Some use normal approximations and work only for large counts and values of $\lambda.$ Some are based on Bayesian methods. Some seek to invert an exact test for $H_0: \lambda=\lambda_0$ vs. $\ne.$ That is 95% CI consists of all values $\lambda_0$ that would not lead to rejection for the data at hand. // In order for this question to be meaningful/answerable, you need to say more about the purpose of the CI, amount of data, criteria and methods.

Comment: One 'inverted test' type of CI based on $n$ iid observations of $X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ so that $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(n\lambda).$ Then assume $T$ aprx normal, solve messy quadratic eqn and conflate 1.96 with 2 to simplify, getting 95% CI $T+2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{T+1}$ for $n\lambda$ and divide by $n$.

Comment: @BruceET my problem is how to argue to go from where I left to the normal formula. In my numeric example $n=200$, so the normal approximation as well as $\chi^2$ both work well. I just need to find a way to argue that they are applicable and don't know how to argue exactly.